# Continues SQL queries on PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, refresh

I have a PHP script that takes an array of `Instance-ID` (int) and performs a SQL query for each one, writing the results to a table.

I want to refresh the data from the database every X seconds (or with every new data) but I couldn't find a way to do so.

```
function checkStatus()
{   
    global $instances_ID;
    // Create connection
    $con=mysqli_connect("*******","*****","*****","****"); 

   // Check connection
   if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    //Clear page
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
    echo "document.body.innerHTML = ''";
    echo "</script>";   

    echo "<h3><center>Last Backups:</center></h3><br><br>";

    //Build table
    echo "<table border='1'align='center'>
    <tr>
    <th>Instance ID</th>
    <th>Backup ID</th>
    <th>STATUS</th>
    <th>Start Time</th>
    <th>End Time</th>
    <th>Progress</th>
    <th>Servlet</th>
    </tr>";
    foreach ($instances_ID as $id)
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `instance_backups` WHERE INSTANCE_ID='".$id."' ORDER BY `instance_backups`.`START_TIMESTAMP` DESC LIMIT 1");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['INSTANCE_ID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['INSTANCE_BACKUP_ID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['STATUS'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['START_TIMESTAMP'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['END_TIMESTAMP'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['PROGRESS_PERCENTAGE'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><input type=button onClick=location.href='******' value='Immidiate Backup'>";
    echo "</tr>";       
    }

    echo "</table>";
    //Close the connection
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: _setInterval_ now google this term.

Comment: you have to use `AJAX` with `setInterval()`, so that every interval of time the ajax request fetch the fresh data.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need a javascript library.  I highly suggest jQuery.  Download the most current version, and upload it to your server, preferably uploading it to a separate folder like 'jscripts' or something.

Now research setInterval().  Use a small and quick function to show its usefulness. setInterval( function name, x )   -- calls a function every x milliseconds.  If you do this:

```
function addText(){
    document.getElementById('testDiv').innerHTML = " HELLO ";
}
setInterval( addText, 1000 );
```

you would see that, if you had a div with the id='testDiv' that every 1 second it would add ' HELLO ' to the div, populating it endlessly.

Now, you research "jquery ajax" .  This is more involved and I will not go over here in detail because of the many steps involved in this question, however, AJAX basically makes a background-connection to another script, and can fetch the output from it, all without refreshing the page.  Once you link the three, you'll be laughing ...

Comment: Just want to add that you don't _need_ a javascript library but it can make the process a little easier. [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) is the Object that the libraries use to do an AJAX request.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but unless you're doing some crazy javascript, need shorter load times and possibly only supporting one browser, you do need it, otherwise the headache is much larger than need be.  Your comment is accurate, nonetheless.